# Date entry feed is wrong even when both Server/Client are in same timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

**Pre-conditions:**

1. Both my server and client machines have same timezone,i.e. India Standard Time (UTC +5:30).
2. I am using Meteor JS 1.5 + MongoDB 3.2 on CentOS 6.9
3. I have set the linux server `/etc/localtime/` to **Asia/Kolkata** and when I gave command `date`, it showed me below,

`Wed Jul 12 13:40:25 IST 2017`

**Actions:**

Below is the peice of code that runs on server methods,

```
History.insert({
  "time": new Date(),
});
```

Since the code ran at **13:40PM IST**, the date entry show in mongoDb is as below,

```
> db.History.find({}).pretty();
{
        "_id" : "zFHFgBfGL2JxNR95N",
        "time" : ISODate("2017-07-12T08:10:10.175Z"),
        "result" : 1
}
```

**Question:**

Why the date entry made using Meteor JS is not the same as of set timezone? and why not the same as the machine *(which is appx 13:40PM)*?

Comment: Where is your database (mongoDB) installed ?  AWS ? or on your local machine ?

Comment: mongoDb is installed on same linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `IST is UTC +5:30`, so 13:40 IST is the same time as 08:10 UTC.

Now checking the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/) on the date type:

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)

Note that the timezone is not being stored at all.

Further down in the same doc:

> The mongo shell wraps objects of Date type with the ISODate helper; however, the objects remain of type Date.

This is why you are seeing `ISODate("2017-07-12T08:10:10.175Z")` being returned when you query in the Mongo Shell

If you switch to the [Meteor Shell](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorshell) and query your data, it will be shown as a javascript Date type again, and in the timezone defined on your server.

```
// try this in Meteor Shell
History.find({}).fetch()
```

And again if you send this date to the client, there it would be displayed with the timezone defined on their device.